# OData:Wildcard (startswith) filtering for number (ID) fields in the url request

Tags: javascript, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-data-services, odata

I've been researching a way to perform fuzzy searches for my numerical ID fields of my entity via OData and JavaScript.  So far, I have not found the answer I am looking for. I can filter other edm.string columns perfectly using the "Startswith" filter option, however when i attempt to pass in any other non-string type, I get a type error response from the server back.

In applications that I control the database, I was successfully able to get around this, by creating views I need and converting the numerical type of the view to a string. However, this seems a bit overkill to go out of my way and create a view for an entire set of data just so I can allow a user to wildcard search the ID, when otherwise the OData query works perfectly well.

Has anyone found a good solution to this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you've already discovered one of the best solutions (creating a view). You could also create a service operation that allows you to do fuzzy search.

What are you using for your backend? This isn't supported on LINQ-to-Entities, but you might be able to create a service operation that looks something like this (to prove that it can work, you can stuff a `ToList()` call in there after `Products`, just be sure not to deploy something like that to production :)):

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class ScratchService : DataService<ScratchContext>
{

    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<Product> FuzzySearch(string idStartsWith)
    {
        var context = new ScratchContext();
        return context.Products.Where(p => p.ID.ToString().StartsWith(idStartsWith));
    }
    // ...
}
```

It's not an ask we've heard a lot, but I can definitely bring it up on the team and as we start the OASIS standardization process it's something we can be thinking about.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am using my own custom WCF Data Service with EntityFramework and Sql Server back end. I was also able to do what you mentioned above, which would work great except for I then lost my inlinecount url option as well. Which I need for many of my applications to show the user total results without the need to make another call back just to retrieve a count. I think it would be really great if the Service Methods would take all the options that regular entity queries did. That way if you build common data access components on the front end you could use either.

Comment: This seems to be a common request for our applications, because we write business applications for our internal customers that are usually very interested in querying straight to the order or part number they are looking for. Giving them a fuzzy search often helps since out IDs can be quite large, and they know it was in the "8600 series" or results. These searches are often in live filtering components (key up starts the search) so having this on large IDs makes for a consistent user filtering experience

Comment: You can still use $inlinecount with your query - in my case the URL looks like http://localhost:59803/ScratchService.svc/FuzzySearch?idStartsWith='1'&$inlinecount=allpages. There are definitely other system query options you can't use.